Unable to cast object of type RemoteJSRuntime to IJSInProcessRuntime when using jQWidgets with Blazor
I had an error when using jQWidgets in the Blazor project (.NET 8) following this tutorial: https://blazor.jqwidgets.com/documentation/jQWidgets
The specific code is just the table following this tutorial: https://blazor.jqwidgets.com/blazor-treegrid/index.htm#https://blazor.jqwidgets.com/blazor-treegrid/blazor-treegrid-defaultfunctionality.htm
The only difference I had is that I downloaded jQWidgets.Blazor by NuGet.
No build error when I access the page, the console shows: Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteJSRuntime' to type 'Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSInProcessRuntime'.
Anyone know the reason why or how to fix it?
